# Pandas merge function based on the last value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes I want to merge those based on the time value  ( or String value ) of the dataframe 2

Dataframe 1

```
  index  Time    Grade
    0    3.00    A    
    1    3.30    B    
    2    4.00    C   
    3    4.30    D    
    4    5.00    E
```

Dataframe 2

```
   index Time  Val
    0    3.30   1050
    1    5.00   2014
```

Output

```
   index Time  Grade  Val
    0    3.00    A    1050
    1    3.30    B    1050
    2    4.00    C    2014
    3    4.30    D    2014
    4    5.00    E    2014
```

Comment: What did you already try? Please share your code. What concrete issues are you facing? Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge_asof`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with `direction='forward'`:

```
df = pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='Time',direction='forward')
print (df)
   Time Grade   Val
0   3.0     A  1050
1   3.3     B  1050
2   4.0     C  2014
3   4.3     D  2014
4   5.0     E  2014
```